# Installing Mozart or other software with Wine

Tags: installation, wine

from very new user of Ubuntu, with Wine installed too.
 I have "Mozart" music notation software, on a CD. I know others use it with Wine. I know it would install on Windows OK, but do I just stick it in my newly all-Ubuntu machine to install here, or do I need to do more to tell it to work with Wine?
if so, what, and where, please?
 Please bear in mind my complete lack of jargon in reply! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Wine AppDB entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2558) for the specific program version you have, since there may be additional issues. You should be able to just install Wine from the software center and then place the CD in the tray. Open the CD in the file manager or from the desktop and right click the Autorun file to run it with Wine.

Comment: Good, that worked, thank you; except just clicking on Autorun file got a "can't do this" response, but when I right-clicked it, it offered me the option of allowing Wine to do the work, which was fine.